# DSP Java FFt Jtransform

Tags: java, fft

In my project I have a file with EEG probes (16338 probes, 256 Hz sampling rate). It looks like this:

[image: probe file]

In my program I need to swap from time domain to frequency domain. I'm using Jtransform lib to do that but I got stuck with it.
I already loaded my columns with probes in `double` arrays and doing doublecomplex FFT from Jtransform lib. Code looks like this:

```
int N= chanel.length;
int Fs=256;
double re;
double im;
double fft[]=new double[N*2];
double[] magnitude = new double[N/2];

//System.arraycopy(chanel,0,fft,0,chanel.length);

for (int i=0; i<N-1; i++)
{
  fft[2*i]=chanel[i];
  fft[2*i+1]=0;
}

DoubleFFT_1D fftDo =new DoubleFFT_1D(N);
fftDo.complexForward(fft);

for(int i=0;i<N/2-1;i++)
{
  re=fft[2*i];
  im=fft[2*i+1];

  magnitude[i]=Math.sqrt(re*re+im*im);
}

double max_magnitude =-999999999;
int max_index = -1;
for (int i=0; i<N/2-1;i++)
{
  if (magnitude[i]>max_magnitude)
  {
    max_magnitude=magnitude[i];
    max_index=i;
  }
}

double dominantFreq =  max_index*Fs/N;
```

Those are the outputs of the different parts of that code:

[image: Outputs]

I read a lot of articles about DSP and was trying to get some advice from my professor but he gave me only a few math formulas that I don't quite understand. I need to draw chart of frequency domain but I still don't know how to get those frequencies from that point (I know it's stupid because it's so close to the solution but I can't figure it out after a week of reading about DSP). So my question is:

Can somebody try to explain it to my the easiest way or show in a pseudo code or some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you started with 256Hz sampled data, and you have 16388 bins the result should be in steps of 0.015621186 Hz per bin.  You can graph the magnitude against the frequency counting up by 0.01562 Hz every bin as you go, up to 128 Hz (sample rate/2).  One way to do that is put the magnitude data in Excel and multiply the cell number by 0.01562 to get the frequency, then select it all and create a graph.

Here I have modified one of your loops to output the frequencies as well.

```
double step = Fs/N; // 0.015621186;
double freq = 0;
double freqs[] = double[N/2];
for(int i=0;i<N/2-1;i++)
{
    re=fft[2*i];
    im=fft[2*i+1];

    magnitude[i]=Math.sqrt(re*re+im*im);
    freqs[i] = freq;

    freq = freq + step;
}
```

Otherwise you could use a Java graphing library.

Conceptually each of these magnitude numbers is the magnitude of all the sine waves in the bin between the frequency bounds of the bin added together.

In summary, you have the data and just need to graph it.  You could also show the "dominant frequency" that you found on the graph to see how that looks.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one more question how did you get this step value? Im gonna need to get it from every other input file.